# Angular - Pass data to parent component

Tags: angular

I have in my parent component this:

```
 obj: any = { row1: [], row2: [], total: [], sumTotal: 0 };
```

I pass obj to child component :

```
<tr table-tr-tr *ngFor="let key1 of channels[name];let i=index" [key1]="key1" [data]="array" [field]="key1"
      [width]="width" [plantype]="plantype" [custom]="custom" [i]="i" [row]="row" [obj]="obj"></tr>
  </table>
```

In child component i have this:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    for (let index = 0; index < this.data.length; index++) {
      this.array.push({ code: index, value: 0 });
    }
    this.obj['row2'][this.field] = this.array;

  }
```

Inside this child component i have another child component where i change values of array but its not changing on my parent object. Any suggestion how can i achive this?

Comment: Have you tried using `EventEmitter` to emit events from child component to parent component? Data flow between parent and child components is not two-way in Angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Inside this child component i have another child component where i
>   change values of array but its not changing on my parent object.

Data flow between parent and child components is not two-way in Angular. So the changes you make in a child component won't be reflected in the parent component.

You can use `EventEmitter` to emit events from child component to parent component.

**Child component:**

In your child component, declare an `EventEmitter` object.

```
@Output() updateObjDataEvent: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
```

Then use `emit` method from anywhere in the child component to send data to parent component.

```
// Update parent component data.
this.updateObjDataEvent.emit(obj);
```

**Parent component:**

In your parent component template, subscribe to this event:

```
<app-child-component-selector (updateObjDataEvent)="updateObj($event)">
</app-child-component-selector>
```

Then in your parent component, create `updateObj()` method to handle data updates from child component.

```
updateObj(data) {
  // Do something.
}
```

In the `updateObj()` method, you can update your parent component's array object.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using services to pass values from one component to another.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=69VeYoKzL6I

Comment: services are not easily controlled like input , unsubscribe and so on...

Comment: Using event emitters can help, but remember there is no two way communication