# How to populate Angular nested component in ngFor loop?

Tags: angular, angular7

I have a nested component in html side like following:

```
<main>
   <ng-content *ngFor="let item in data">
     <car *ngIf="item.type=='car'"></car>
     <plane *ngIf="item.type=='car'"></plane>
   </ng-content>
</main>
```

My `car` and `plane` components are implemented a base cehicle class.

```
export abstract class BaseVehicleComponent{
    onVehicleCreated(){
        console.log("on vehicle created.")
    }
}
```

When a vehicle created, I want to populate an event in `main` component.

```
@Component({
   selector: 'main',
})
export class MainComponent{

     @Output() vehicleCreated = new EventEmitter<void>();

}
```

And hml updated like this:

```
<main (vehicleCreated)="onVehicleCreated($event)">
   <ng-content *ngFor="let item in data">
     <car *ngIf="item.type=='car'"></car>
     <plane *ngIf="item.type=='car'"></plane>
   </ng-content>
</main>
```

but base methot does not fire.

Comment: Where are you calling `this.vehicleCreated.emit()`?

Comment: It would be helpful if you create an example on StackBlitz.

Comment: Actually nowhere, where can I cal?.Main component and vehicle components are seperated, and may be different modules. So I want to do a loosely coupled communication.

Comment: @barteloma - Check out my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BaseVehicleComponent` should have `EventEmitter` not `MainComponent`.

**BaseVehicleComponent:**

```
export abstract class BaseVehicleComponent{
   @Output() vehicleCreated = new EventEmitter<void>();
}
```

`MainComponent` should have `onVehicleCreated()` function not `BaseVehicleComponent`.

**MainComponent:**

```
export class MainComponent{  
  onVehicleCreated(){
    console.log("on vehicle created.")
  }
}
```

In `car` or `plane` components' `ngOnInit()` method call event emitter's `emit()` method.

```
this.vehicleCreated.emit();
```

Modify `MainComponent`'s template to be

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item in data">
  <car *ngIf="item.type=='car' (vehicleCreated)="onVehicleCreated($event)"></car>
  <plane *ngIf="item.type=='plane' (vehicleCreated)="onVehicleCreated($event)"></plane>
</ng-container>
```

Live demo on StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-thvzue

For more info, check out my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57813231/2924577) on communication between parent and child components.

Comment: @barteloma - Check out my edited answer. You can also see this working on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-thvzue).

Comment: I put my html <main> and <ng-container> in app.component.html, so an error occured because of onVehicleCreated() not found.

Comment: No, just put `<main>` in `app-component`. You can see how I did it in the StackBlitz.

Comment: Can I put in app.component.html and fire onVehicleCreated() of mainComponent?

Comment: But then `data` variable should be placed in `app-component`. Also then what is the purpose of `main-component` when you are placing all the components directly in `app-component`?