# Angular multiple checkbox value

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, checkbox

A student wants to register one class or more than one class. As the class list is dynamic, I have used ngFor to display in a table format with checkbox at then end to select the class. But, no idea how to get value when a student checkbox to select class.

I have tried to use the select option but that didn't go through well.

```
<div>
<table align="center" >
  <tr class="heading" >
    <th style="padding: 5px;">Code</th>
    <th style="padding: 5px;">Name</th>
    <th style="padding: 5px;">Capacity</th>
    <th style="padding: 5px;">Remaining</th>
    <th style="padding: 5px;">Location</th>
    <th style="padding: 5px;">Instructor</th>
    <th style="padding: 5px;">Register?</th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let item of classItem">
    <td style="border-right-style: dashed;">{{ item.Code }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.Name }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.Capacity }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.Remaining }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.Location }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.Instructor }}</td>
    <td>
      <ion-checkbox style="text-align: center;" (onchange)="checkboxChange()" [(ngModel)]="checkItem"></ion-checkbox>
    </td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

I expect when student register for any class then, capacity of class will be reduced by one and update to firebase database.

Comment: Check this out [User does not have permission to access this object . Firebase storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38671444/user-does-not-have-permission-to-access-this-object-firebase-storage-android)

Answer (score 1):

Since you have multiple checkboxes, you need an array to keep track of these checkboxes.

**Component:**

```
checkboxes = [];
```

Initialize all checkboxes with `false` to keep them unchecked at the beginning.

```
ngOnInit() {
  // This array will be the same length as the iterable object used in *ngFor.
  this.checkboxes = new Array(this.classItem.length).fill(false);
}
```

**Template:**

In the template, bind each checkbox to their respective value.

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of classItem; let i = index">
  ...
  <ion-checkbox style="text-align: center;" (onchange)="checkboxChange(i)"
    [(ngModel)]="checkboxes[i]"></ion-checkbox>
  ...
</tr>
```

When a checkbox is checked or unchecked, modify available capacity of the class.

```
checkboxChange(i) {
  if (this.checkboxes[i]) {
    this.capacity++;
  } else {
    this.capacity--;
  }
}
```

Comment: I have capacity variable in another page, how would I link to this page?

Comment: @RaviShankarShah - If you have the variable in a parent component, then you can update it by sending the data using event emitters. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57813231/2924577) for more info. If the components are not related, then look at communicating between components using a service. If you are having trouble doing this, ask a new question since it isn't related to this checkbox question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution to your problem. Firstly I added component ts file with mock data in checkItem array of type ClassDescription with ClassDescription interface. 
Note that I have used normal html input checkbox instead  , I just verified on ionic documentation and it will work same as below reference of [`Ionic Checkbox`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/checkbox)

```
<table align="center" >
  <tr class="heading" >
    <th style="padding: 5px;">Code</th>
    <th style="padding: 5px;">Name</th>
    <th style="padding: 5px;">Capacity</th>
    <th style="padding: 5px;">Remaining</th>
    <th style="padding: 5px;">Location</th>
    <th style="padding: 5px;">Instructor</th>
    <th style="padding: 5px;">Register?</th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let item of classItem">
    <td style="border-right-style: dashed;">{{ item.code }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.capacity }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.remaining }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.location }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.instructor }}</td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox"  [(ngModel)]="item.register"  (change)="onChecked(item)" 
[disabled]="(item.remaining === 0) && item.register == !true"> 

      <br>
    </td>


  </tr>

  </table>
```

My Stackblitz solution is here [`Stackblitz solution`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ayrths). Next you can add your logic for firebase inside onChecked function.

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    interface ClassDescription {
    code : string; 
    name : string ; 
    capacity: string ; 
    remaining : number ; 
    location : string ; 
    instructor : string; 
    register: boolean; 
    }
   @Component({
   selector: 'my-app',
   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
   styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
   })
  export class AppComponent  {

     onChecked(item) {
     if(item.register)
       {
         item.remaining = item.remaining - 1 ;
       }
      else{
          item.remaining = item.remaining + 1 ;
        }  

     }

    classItem: ClassDescription[]= [
   {
      'code' : '101',
      'name' : 'Micro services',
      'capacity': '30',
      'remaining' : 5 ,
      'location' : 'Engineering dept',
      'instructor' : 'Dr. Neha',
      'register': false 
    },
    {
       'code' : '102',
      'name' : 'Computer Science',
      'capacity': '30',
      'remaining' : 0 ,
      'location' : 'Mcarthy hall',
      'instructor' : 'Dr. Rob',
       'register': false 
     },
    {
      'code' : '103',
     'name' : 'Programming fundamental',
      'capacity': '30',
     'remaining' : 5 ,
     'location' : 'Harvard hall',
     'instructor' : 'Dr. Steven',
      'register': false 
     }
     ];


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table align="center" >
  <tr class="heading" >
    <th style="padding: 5px;">Code</th>
    <th style="padding: 5px;">Name</th>
    <th style="padding: 5px;">Capacity</th>
    <th style="padding: 5px;">Remaining</th>
    <th style="padding: 5px;">Location</th>
    <th style="padding: 5px;">Instructor</th>
    <th style="padding: 5px;">Register?</th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let item of classItem;let i = index">
    <td style="border-right-style: dashed;">{{ item.code }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.capacity }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.remaining }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.location }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.instructor }}</td>
    <td>
      <ion-checkbox style="text-align: center;" (ionChange)="checkboxStateChanged(i)" [checked]="item.checked"></ion-checkbox>
    </td>


  </tr>

  </table>
```

**in your ts :**

```
classSelectedIndexes : number[] = []; //storing the selected item indexes just in case  

checkboxStateChanged(index : number){
 this.item[i].checked= !this.item[i].checked;
 if(this.item[i].checked){
  //do something if true
 }
  else{
  //do something if false
 }
}
```

It is expected to have a `checked` property in your `classItem` all initialized to `false`

i.e your `classItem` should be of type :

```
interface ClassType {
code : string; 
name : string ; 
capacity: string ; 
remaining : number ; 
location : string ; 
instructor : string; 
checked: boolean; 
}
```